# Unable to see shapefile on the device

Tags: arcgis-10.1, android

I am trying to add london shapefile for buildings in my android app. However, I am unable to display it. Its showing nothing on the map. But the same shapefile is getting displayed properly online. So, there is nothing wrong with the shapefile.

I downloaded shapefile from
https://docs.google.com/uc?id=0B0kRhiw4fD7uQzU3MzBMRzFfSFk&export=download

[image]

My code:
layout.xml

```
<!-- MapView layout and initial basemap and extent. -->


<com.esri.android.map.MapView
    android:id="@+id/map"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    mapoptions.ZoomLevel="5"
    mapoptions.center="18.0000, 79.5800" >
</com.esri.android.map.MapView>
```

MapActivity.java

```
    mMapView = (MapView) findViewById(R.id.map);
    mMapView.enableWrapAround(true);
    String mShapefilePath = "/london_buildings/TQTL_LON.shp";

    String mSdcard = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath();

    mMapView = (MapView) findViewById(R.id.map);
    ArcGISTiledMapServiceLayer mTiledlayer = new ArcGISTiledMapServiceLayer(
            "http://services.arcgisonline.com/arcgis/rest/services/ESRI_Imagery_World_2D/MapServer");

    mMapView.addLayer(mTiledlayer);

    try {
        shpFileFeatTable = new ShapefileFeatureTable(mSdcard + mShapefilePath);
        mFlayer = new FeatureLayer(shpFileFeatTable);
        mFlayer.setRenderer(new SimpleRenderer(new SimpleMarkerSymbol(Color.CYAN, 2, STYLE.SQUARE)));

        mMapView.addLayer(mFlayer);
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "File not found in SDCard, nothing to load", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                .show();
    } catch (RuntimeException e) {
        Log.d("**ShapefileTest**", "File not found in SDCard, nothing to load");
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "File not found in SDCard, nothing to load", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                .show();
    }
```

Comment: Is there an error message? Are any exceptions thrown?

Comment: No exceptions. It showed me online map

Comment: How is this different from your previous post?

Comment: Have you tried using a zoomlevel of 12, as suggested in the other question? Also, 18.0, 79.58 is not London. Try 51.5,0 for London.